# Laravel - Assertion multiple regex

Tags: php, regex, laravel, assert

I have two regex :

```
'/^(?:0(?:21|9[0-9]))?[0-9]{8}$/'
```

And

```
'/(0|\\+98 | 98)?([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}9[1|2|3|4]([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}(?:[0-9]([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}){8}/'
```

I want to use **Assertion::regex** method in **Laravel**. Here is that method:

**Assertion.php:**

```
public static function regex($value, $pattern, $message = null, $propertyPath = null)
{
    static::string($value, $message, $propertyPath);

    if (! preg_match($pattern, $value)) {
        $message = sprintf(
            $message ?: 'Value "%s" does not match expression.',
            static::stringify($value)
        );

        throw static::createException($value, $message, static::INVALID_REGEX, $propertyPath, array('pattern' => $pattern));
    }

    return true;
}
```

How to use and check multiple regex in *Assertion::regex($phone, $regex);* ?

I used to initialize $regex with :

```
$regex = '/^(?:0(?:21|9[0-9]))?[0-9]{8}$/ | /(0|\\+98 | 98)?([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}9[1|2|3|4]([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}(?:[0-9]([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}){8}/'
```

Actually , I gave an error :

> preg_match(): Unknown modifier '|'

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your first regex is anchored, and the second one is not. Is it intended? If yes, you may use [`(?:^(?:0(?:21|9[0-9]))?[0-9]{8}$|(0|\+98 | 98)?[- ,()]{0,2}9[1-4][- ,()]{0,2}(?:[0-9][- ,()]{0,2}){8})`](https://regex101.com/r/1ssxXA/3). If not, try [`^(?:(?:0(?:21|9[0-9]))?[0-9]{8}|(0|\+98 | 98)?[- ,()]{0,2}9[1-4][- ,()]{0,2}(?:[0-9][- ,()]{0,2}){8})$`](https://regex101.com/r/1ssxXA/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an alternation between two regexes the pipe must be within the regex:

```
^(?:0(?:21|9[0-9]))?[0-9]{8}$|(0|\\+98 | 98)?([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}9[1|2|3|4]([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}(?:[0-9]([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}){8}
                             ^
```

The string concatenation you did lead php to understand that your regex finished after this backslash:

```
/^(?:0(?:21|9[0-9]))?[0-9]{8}$/
                              ^
```

Trying to interpret what followed as modifiers, thus the error message you've got.